# Create points from a grid using R

Tags: r, r-sp

I hope to achieve a `.csv` file with a list of coordinates corresponding to the centre of each grid square on a `plot`.

I've been able to map the `polygon` and overlay a `grid`, however I'm not sure what will be required to a) plot points in the centre of each grid square, and b) extract the coordinates from the points - although the later should fall out once a) is complete.

Grid Plot is shown below:

[image: Grid Plot]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
  First we need to make a regular grid
      NGSA.grid=spsample(NGSA.union, n = 1000, type="regular", nsig = 2,    offset = c(0.5,0.5),pretty = FALSE)
      str(NGSA.grid)
      gridded(NGSA.grid)=TRUE
      plot(NGSA.grid,pch=19,cex=0.1,col="green",axes=TRUE)
      plot(NGSA.OGR, add=TRUE, pch=16, cex=0.5)
      proj4string(NGSA.grid)==proj4string(NGSA.OGR)
```

Comment: Does `coordinates(NGSA.grid)` give you a matrix of coordinates? I can't tell because we don't have your data so we can't run your code. Please try and make an example with data we can all use, such as the sample data from the `sp` or `rgdal` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First follow `?readOGR` to create the `scot_BNG` object which I'll be using here.

Then create gridded object:

```
> scotgrid = spsample(scot_BNG, n=1000, type="regular", nsig=2, pretty=FALSE)
> gridded(scotgrid)=TRUE
```

Then the `coordinates` function gets you the grid centres. Note you could just use the `scotgrid` object created above *before* you made it a `gridded` object. At that point its a `SpatialPoints` object. Anyway:

```
> head(coordinates(scotgrid))
           x1       x2
[1,] 211728.1 535835.7
[2,] 247407.1 535835.7
[3,] 238487.4 544755.4
[4,] 247407.1 544755.4
[5,] 265246.6 544755.4
[6,] 274166.3 544755.4
```

And if you want to plot the cell centres over the grid you can just use `points`, which extracts those cell coordinates before plotting:

```
> plot(scotgrid)
> points(scotgrid,pch=19,col="red",cex=.25)
```

[image: points in grid cells]

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for your detailed response